# How to reference data around function in object without traversing entire object?

Tags: javascript, oop

Having an object similar to:

```js
const data = {
  tasks: {
    projects: [
      name:'Project Name',
      filters: [
        {
          name:'First Project Filter',
          checked:false,
          onChange:(event) => {
            console.log(this.checked)
          }
        },
        ...
      ],
      ...
    ],
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

**The problem at hand is how to reference the checked property without drilling through the entire object.**

In the case above, it throws an error because `this` is undefined, so referencing `this.checked` is invalid.

> I could extract from the event data properties so that I can get the
>   whole reference such as `tasks.projects[0].filters[0].checked`, but I
>   am wondering if an easier method is available.

The ideal solution would be a way to reference the surrounding properties of the function without traversing the entire object. Surely the function has a way to know that it is inside of an object so maybe something like `parent().checked` ?

*If relative*: I am using node.js and react to use this object to render a filtered sidebar that works with context to filter the data-set. I don't think that is relative as this seems like a pure JavaScript OOP situation.

Comment: Try regular instead of arrow function.

Comment: I just was reading another question on here and thought about this scope in arrow functions, ugh! Let me give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: @NenadVracar that is the answer and solution to this question. If you want to put it into an answer form I will accept it.